# Python 3.4 - NNTPLIB - Port Not Bound - Is there a Firewall Enabled? - Aptana 3.6.1

Tags: java, python-3.x, aptana3, nntp

I have tried reinstalling aptana studio as well as java. I have java 8, update 45 installed. Aptana studio 3.6.1. Whenever I try to import nntplib this is the error I get. I'm not sure what else to try.

My ultimate goal is to stream news from a free news site (http://nntp.freeservers.com/) to an EC2 mapr hadoop cluster using flume so I can do real time sentiment analytics.